# Dagger for Android: Injecting an Activity to the object graph after calling setContentView

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger

I want to use Dagger on Android to inject an instance of an `Activity` into another class as follows:

```
class PresentationLayer{
    Activity mActivity;
    
    @Inject
    public PresentationLayer(Activity activity){
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }
    
    public void presentData(User user){
        ((TextView)mActivity.findViewById(R.id.username))
            .setText(user.getName());
        //...
        //...
    }
}
```

I am able to do the injection, but all fields of the `Activity` are **`null` at the time of injection**.

Here's how I am doing the injection:

My `Activity` is a module in itself.

```
@Module(
    complete = false
)
class MainActivity extends Activity{
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        ObjectGraph objectGraph = CustomApplication.getObjectGraph();
        PresentationLayer pres = objectGraph.get(PresentationLayer.class);
    }
    
    @Provides Activity provideActivity(){
        return this;
    }
    
    
}
```

This is my main module

```
@Module(
    entryPoints = PresentationLayer.class,
    includes = MainActivity.class
)
class DaggerModule{
    @Provides PresentationLayer providePresentation(Activity activity){
        return new PresentationLayer(activity);
    }
}
```

And my `Application` class that bootstraps the object graph.

```
class CustomApplication extends Application{

    private static ObjectGraph sObjectGraph;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        sObjectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(new DaggerModule());
    }
    
    static getObjectGraph(){
        return sObjectGraph;
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to explicitly perform the injection **after I call `setContentView`**.

How do I go about doing this?

---

#### EDIT 1:

I got it to work like this - however I am not sure if this is the "right way". What I do is

1. Pass in the Activity to the `Module` constructor
2. Ensure that I build the `ObjectGraph` *after* I do `setContentView()` so that a proper `Activity` instance is passed in to the `ObjectGraph`.

My `Activity` is no longer a dagger `Module`.

This translates to the following in code:

```
@Module(
    entryPoints = PresentationLayer.class
)
class DaggerModule{

    private Activity mActivity;
    
    public DaggerModule (Activity activity){
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }
    
    @Provides PresentationLayer providePresentation(){
        return new PresentationLayer(mActivity);
    }
}
```

And this is how my `Activity` looks:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity{
    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        ObjectGraph objectGraph = CustomApplication.getObjectGraph(this);
        PresentationLayer pres = objectGraph.get(PresentationLayer.class);
        User user = //get the user here
        pres.presentData(user);
    }
}
```

This solution seems to address the points raised by Jesse Wilson in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13992119/570930). However, I am concerned about the performance, since the `ObjectGraph` is going to be built **every time the `Activity` is created**.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Unfortunately this probably isn't going to work with Dagger, or with most other dependency injection frameworks. The problem is that the lifecycle of `Activity` doesn't cleanly line up with the lifecycle of `PresentationLayer`. For example, when you rotate your screen, Android will destroy the activity and create another one in its place. There's no hook for `PresentationLayer` to participate in that.

At Square we've been using [Otto](http://square.github.com/otto/) to communicate between activities and their backends and it has worked well. See Eric Burke's [sample code project](https://github.com/eburke/presentations/blob/master/strange_loop_2012/samplecode/src/com/squareup/anatomy/AccountActivity.java) for an example.

Comment: I see the point about `Activity` life-cycle. I edited my question to include what I think is a possible solution. Would like your thoughts on that. My aim is to share modules between a desktop Java app and an Android app. So, the `PresentationLayer` would be a dependency for a `BusinessLogicLayer`. In Android, I configure Dagger to inject Android implementation of PresentationLayer, while in JSE, I inject a different impl of PresLayer (which does not require `Activity` since it just uses `System.out.println`). I would be glad to upload a sample project on github if it helps.

Comment: ObjectGraph creation is cheap, but your singletons may not be. Especially if they're stateful (such as the Otto bus) in which case you don't want to create multiple object graphs. With ObjectGraph.plus(), you can build upon existing graphs. That might help to create a per-activity graph.

Comment: Thanks! Based on your comments, I am leaning towards using a hybrid approach of using Dagger where it is "easy" and to fall back on "manual" DI where using Dagger (or any JSR330 library) becomes unwieldy. By manual DI, I mean either constructing the object myself from my bootstrap class (like a `main` method or `Servlet` or `onCreate()` etc); or using factories to obtain instances of the dependencies wherever required. This is not ideal, but I think it is an acceptable compromise in my use case.